# How to change slice elements using pointers in a loop

Tags: go, pointers

I'm trying to update a bunch of structs in a slice in place using pointers in a loop but they're not being updated.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type X struct {
    ID float32
}

func inc(x *X) {
    x.ID += 10
}

func main() {
    var a = []X{X{}, X{}}

    for _, v := range a {
        inc(&v)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is even a FAQ entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `for _, v := range a`, `v` contains a copy of the element.

Use indexed access instead:

```
for i := range a {
    inc(&a[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct, adding this link here as reference - https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16

> When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration.
> The first is the index, and the second is a copy of the element at
> that index.

Sorry, I can't comment as I don't have the required reputation. So, adding it as answer.